# customized dynamic video production

Tags: html, flash, video

I have a problem to witch i don't know there is a answer. I've been asked to create a personalized video production, for a company. Meaning that a client would see, after introducing his name and photo, a generic video of the company and somehow the name of that client, and photo, should belong to the video. Like a waitress giving a calling card with the client's name.

Basically i want reproduce what **[this company](https://www.impossiblesoftware.com)** offers in a solution developed by me!
Here is an example of this company's work and a perfect example of what i want!

**[EXAMPLE](http://10secondsoffame.usanetwork.com/)** -> Login with Facebook and see your photos dynamically displayed in a video.

I'm almost sure that the solution can be made with flash, but i am open to suggestions.

Thank you in advance for the , i hope,not so very vague question.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOveflow.  Your question is too broad for this site and will likely be closed unless you make it more specific (showing what you've tried, and asking about a specific issue).      I can tell you, that you can do this without using Flash, and indeed should as flash in the web browser is a thing of Legacy and not the future.

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks for the advice.